# Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.LinuxDiagnostic mdsd.warn filesize growing huge in Azure Classic VM (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine

Noticed that suddenly I'm running low on disk space on my Azure Classic VM (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS). Found the culprit by running

```
du --max-depth=1 --human-readable / | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

The disk space was taken by mdsd.warn file in logs: /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.LinuxDiagnostic/2.0.9023/ and it was growing with about 2GB/hour.

Now, I know this is part of the Azure Linux diagnostics and did the following:
1) Disabled diagnostics in Azure Portal for the said server
2) Removed the OSTCExtensions LinuxDiagnostic through the Azure Portal

This did not change anything the thing that bloads the mdsd.warn file is a log entry:

> 2017-09-27T18:41:18.3566560Z: Event source tag-reader is slow; dropping tag 1505081343:1422134.88339207

My questions:
What is this warning the file is filled with?
How can this be fixed?

I thought the dropping the extension itself would stop this but no - no go. As I have dropped the extension, can the diagnostics be stopped etc?